# My one-line-rewriter only rewrites part of a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Having run this through a 25-line script, it only turned the first 20 lines into one line. This script also removes comments, which it also did only on the first 20 lines. Why does it ignore the last five lines?

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def make_one_line(f):
    uncommented_lines = (line.rstrip('\n').split('#')[0] for line in f) 
    return ';'.join(uncommented_lines)


print "This will rewrite the file, press CTRL-C to cancel."
raw_input('Press any key (but CTRL-C) to continue.')

current_file = open(input_file, 'r+')
final = make_one_line(current_file)
current_file.truncate()
current_file.seek(0) # if this isn't here, you get an error on Windows
current_file.write(final)
```

This is the script I tested it on:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def reverse_file(f):
    # reads the file, then adds each character to a list,
    # then reverses them
    final = ''
    text_body = f.read()
    chars = list(text_body)
    chars.reverse()
    # this puts the characters from the list into a string
    for i in chars:
        final += i
    return final

print "This will rewrite the file, press CTRL-C to cancel."
print "(Although you can undo the damage by just running this again.)"
raw_input('Press any key (but CTRL-C) to continue.')

current_file = open(input_file, 'r+')   
final = reverse_file(current_file)
current_file.truncate()
current_file.seek(0) # if this isn't here, you get an error on Windows
current_file.write(final)
```

Comment: its hard to understand the question you are asking

Comment: You are overwriting an existing file. Does everything work as expected if you create a new file instead?

Comment: @BasSwinckels I'm so noob at this I don't know HOW to create a new file.

Comment: You know 1-lineifying a script won't produce a working script, right?

Comment: @Noelkd I'm asking why it ignores the last five lines.

Comment: What actually happens to the last five lines? Do they not appear in the output at all? Do they appear on separate lines? It may be worth pasting the output into the question, despite the horrible horizontal scrolling that will be required to read it.

Comment: add     `still_has_new_line = "\n" in final;
    print "HAVE WE REMOVED ALL THE NEW LINES:", still_has_new_line` to after where you get final

Comment: @AndrewPampuch `outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w'); outfile.write(xx)`

Comment: The last 5 lines are still there, they look exactly as they did before being run through the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are having the problem because of mixed newline types: Try this:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def make_one_line(f):
    uncommented_lines = (line.rstrip('\n\r').split('#')[0] for line in f) #
    return ';'.join(uncommented_lines)


#print "This will rewrite the file, press CTRL-C to cancel."
#raw_input('Press any key (but CTRL-C) to continue.')

current_file = open(input_file, 'rU') # Open in universal newline mode
final = make_one_line(current_file)
current_file.close()
outfile = open("out_"+input_file, "wt") # Save the output in a new file
outfile.write(final)
outfile.write('\n')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: The results should be in a new file called out_ then the original file name.